# Statistical analysis with R on a graph

Tags: r

Based on my data, I've got this graph: [image]
With this code:

```
df %>% 
  filter(percent_power < 100) %>% 
  ggscatter(x = "percent_power", y = "relVO2", color = "group") +
  stat_cor(aes(color = group), label.x = 25, label.y = c(5.4,3.8)) +
  stat_regline_equation(label.x = 1, label.y = c(5.4,3.8), 
                        formula = y ~ x,
                        aes(color = group, label =  paste(..eq.label.., ..adj.rr.label.., sep = "~~~~")),) +
  geom_smooth(aes(colour=group), method = "lm", formula = y ~ x) +
  xlab("Percentage of power (%)") + 
  ylab(expression(paste("V", O[2]," (mL/min/kg)")))
```

I would like to make a classic one-way ANOVA to get a p-value and also mean±SD for 25, 50, 75 and 100% of percent of power (x axis).

Does anyone have any idea ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, lot's of great ideas. The best: Instead of posting graphics code it seems more advisable to produce a minimal reproducible example as in https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Also: What seems to be your problem with that AnOVa?

Comment: Building on @Bernhard's comments, it would be useful to know what predictor variables you might want in your model. Presumably group (as a factor) and percentage power.  Would power be a factor or a continuous variable? If a factor, how will you define the levels?  If a continuous variable, do you want to look for non-linear effects?  Are there other predictors you ant to consider?  You also appear to have non-homogeneous variance.  Are you going to try to address that?  At the moment, your question is far too vague to give definitive advice.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. You are right and I will make another question.